# Looking for a book called Redline Fever

Tags: story-identification

When I was in school my Dad had a book called *Redline Fever*. I am looking for the author of the book and a place where I can get it. I know that the story was about a man that drives a truck in the future that has his Dad's memories. Was *Redline Fever* the right name for the book?

Answer (score 11):

[*Red Limit Freeway*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?27606) (1984) by [John DeChancie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_DeChancie) (author of the [*Castle Perilous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Perilous_(series)) series) is the middle book of his [*Skyway*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?7026) trilogy; the first book is [*Starrigger*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33038) (1983) and the third is [*Paradox Alley*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25611) (1987). It's about a truck driver in the future, and the artificial intelligence built into the truck has the personality and memories of the driver's father. The *Skyway* series was also the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/trilogy-involving-time-travel-and-bugs-that-patrol-futuristic-highways). Here is the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_DeChancie#The_Skyway_Series) plot summary:

> The *Skyway* series differs from the *Castle* series significantly; where the *Castle* series is humorous fantasy, the *Skyway* series is action-adventure science fiction. **The *Skyway* series traces the adventures of Jake McGraw, who drives a futuristic cargo truck on the Skyway.** The Skyway itself is a mysterious road, built by an unknown race of aliens, which runs across various planets from one portal to another. Driving through a portal (a "tollbooth") instantaneously transports you onto a different planet, many light years away. Humans found the Skyway on Pluto and began expanding along it, encountering various alien races along the way. However no one has a map, or knows where the Skyway begins or ends, and because each portal is one-way, only explored sections with a known return path (discovered by trial and error) are considered safe to travel.
>
> At the beginning of the first book Jake finds himself in trouble because a number of parties, both human and alien, are convinced that he has found a map. Some are willing to kill to get it. Jake knows that he does not have a map, but no one believes him. **At this point Jake is accompanied only by his father, Sam, who is actually dead but has been "converted" into an artificial intelligence unit that is built into the truck.** The truck itself is a large tractor trailer unit, powered by nuclear fusion and capable of operating in a vacuum. The truck's cab can hold 8 or more people and has built-in bunks for sleeping. At the beginning of the first book Jake stops to pick up a hitchhiker (the beautiful and mysterious Darla), which is the beginning of a trend: over the course of the trilogy more and more people are riding with Jake while more and more people are also pursuing him. By the end of the trilogy Jake and his companions have reached the end of the Skyway, met with the beings that created it, and returned months earlier than when they left, bringing the trilogy to a conclusion.

You should have no trouble finding copies for sale on Amazon or Ebay or Abebooks. Here are some Abebooks search results for [*Starrigger*](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&bx=off&ds=30&recentlyadded=all&sortby=17&sts=t&tn=starrigger) and [*Red Limit Freeway*](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&bx=off&ds=30&recentlyadded=all&sortby=17&sts=t&tn=red+limit+freeway) and [*Paradox Alley*](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&bx=off&ds=30&recentlyadded=all&sortby=17&sts=t&tn=paradox+alley).